# No internet access on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a strange problem with Windows 7. It all started couple of days ago. On my Dell XPS laptop I have two network interfaces, one LAN one WLAN. When I power up my computer I have a small yellow triangle on network icon that says no internet access for my LAN connection. I have an IP address from my DHCP. Ping does not work and tracert outputs this:

```
Tracing route to superuser.com [69.59.196.219]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1  XPS [192.168.1.124]  reports: Destination host unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

The first time this happened I googled a bit found this tip:

```
netsh int ip reset
```

I ran it, rebooted, and it worked. The first time. Next day it didnt work. I ran it a few times, fiddled a bit with networks and it worked. Next day, nothing worked and thats why I'm writing here - cause I'm out of ideas.

And another thing, if I disconnect LAN cable and power on WLAN everything works fine. I wonder for how long.

What should I do? It seems the only solution is to reinstall Windows 7 from scratch but if I'll have to do that every 30 days (yes, I installed it 30 days ago) - screw Windows 7, I'm going back to XP. I need my network to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7, same as Vista, supports only one internet connection, and in addition has the annoying habit of always preferring wired connections over non-wired, on the supposition that they are faster (have better metric).

See this article for a Vista solution with many screenshots :
["Windows Vista Multiple Networks: Wireless To Public WIFI and Wired To Private LAN"](http://www.walkernews.net/2008/10/29/windows-vista-multiple-networks-wireless-to-public-wifi-and-wired-to-private-lan/).

The basic solution is to use the command:

> route delete 0.0.0.0 IF 11

where the IF 11 refers to Inteface List # 11 (which is displayed by route print command output, in the Interface List section). Replace this by the number in your case.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot this was driving me crazy. I just wonder why windows started adding this route all of a sudden.

Comment: It's not for us mortals to wonder why.

Comment: I still have problems, if you can help me, I'll be really grateful - http://superuser.com/questions/51551/no-internet-access-on-windows-7-part-2

Comment: @harrymc even i am facing the same issue as i powern on the dell inspiron there's a no internet access.I don't have any network access so it should should show a red cross over the network but this strange behaviour has appeared since two days.Could you please tell me what is the route print command output so as to try your method

Comment: @user285oo6: I suggest posting your question on the forum with details of your hardware and software, and especially the network card make and driver and the output of the route print command.

Comment: @harrymc how do i get the hardware details,network card make,driver. Also after the route what should type in the cmd prmpt

Comment: @user285oo6: You should find hardware info in the Device Manager. Using route with no parameters will give you its help.

Comment: @harrymc This is the [post](http://superuser.com/questions/876565/no-internet-access-when-there-is-no-ethernet-cable-plugged) here that I have asked.Hope it has all the above mentioned details

Answer (score 0):

Which network connection do you want to use?

As harrymc posted, it is only possible to use one network adapter at the same time. So if it works with WLAN, can you just deactivate the (wired) LAN adapter? Does this help?