# No internet access on Windows 7 - part 2

Tags: windows-7, networking

This is a continuation of my previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/49851/no-internet-access-on-windows-7).

The problems started when I turned on my wireless connection for the first time. Since then, every time I boot my Windows 7, my LAN connection does not have internet access. In my previous question, I got a key answer (route delete). Now my procedure to get LAN internet connectivity (local network works fine) when I boot looks like this:

1. Power on WLAN
2. Disconnect LAN cable
3. Power off WLAN
4. Execute route delete 0.0.0.0 if 11
5. Connect LAN cable

Now my LAN connection has internet access.

Another behavior that I can't explain - while my LAN connection has no internet access, Network and Sharing center refers to it as Unknown network, with a public icon. When I go through the fore mentioned procedure, it is referred to with my home WLAN network name, with status connected, and the Unknown network disappears.

Comment: you should stick to your original question and edit it if you wish to provide additional information.

Comment: My original question was answered and I find that question closed. If there wasn't for first question on this topic there wouldn't be this question at all (and I wouldn't have internet connectivity at all)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.
I made an image of my HDD and then did a fresh install of Windows 7. I installed each piece of software I had originally installed until the problem re-appeared, it was Adobe CS3 causing the problem.

I restored from the image I took and un-installed Adobe Photoshop CS3 that I had installed and I have never had the problem again.
It's beyond me to explain what in Adobe CS3 was causing this problem. But the method should work for you. Use CLonezilla or another imaging solution to do this and follow the path I did, hope it helps.

Comment: Good idea, I'll definitely use this next time I have a strange problem show up.

Comment: I've read threads on MS Technet and elsewhere that indicate the `Bonjour` service installed by Adobe applications and Apple programs (like quicktime and itunes) can result in the "no internet access" problem. For some disabling the service fixes the issue without having to uninstall the application(s).