# Why is the notification area showing no internet access when there is no connection with any network either Wired/Wireless

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

Usually when I power on the laptop near the notification tray for the Internet access it will generally show a small red colour cross.This turns Ethernet if I plug an Ethernet cable or turns into WiFi if there is a WiFi connection connected.

**[Update]**:-

This is what as expected when the windows boots(WiFi is off,No Ethernet connection etc)
[image: The default icon when the Windows is turned on (the WiFi is turned off,no Ethernet connection)]

This is what when the connection is established to WiFi.

[image: The default icon when the connection is established to WiFi]

But since few days it is showing a No internet access.I don't have any internet connection to either a WiFi or the Ethernet cable.

When I try to connect using the WiFi hotspot it is able to connect to the Android device but instead gives a limited connection.

**[Update]**:-
This is how it shows in the notification area when the Windows boots on my laptop and when I point the icon it says no internet access by default.( even when WiFi is turned ON,no Ethernet connection)
[image: The default notification which is showed when the Windows boots on my Laptop showing an exclamatory triangle no internet access]

**What is your question?** 
Why is the notification not showing the default red cross sign on the network notification as it should when I don't have any connection either through the LAN/WiFi

**What do you want to happen?**
Why can't the notification icon for the Network show the default red coloured cross when not connected and show the simple WiFi when connected to a WiFi network
**Software specifications**:-
Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit

**Hardware specifications**:-(as seen from the device manager)

Broadcoam virtual wireless Adapter

Dell Wireless 1701 802.11 b/g/n

Microsoft Virtual WiFi  Miniport adapter

Realtek PCIC FE Family controller

Virtual Host only Ethernet Adapter

> Things tried:-
>
> As per the above mentioned post i have tried the route command in the
>   cmd prompt and it gave the following
>
> route ADD 3ffe::/32 3ffe::1 route CHANGE 157.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0
>   157.55.80.5 METRIC 2 IF 2 route DELETE 157.0.0.0 route DELETE ffe::/32
>
> I have spoken with the technical team of the manufacturer and he says
>   me that i need to do a clean format(Format only the C:\ drive)
>   **[Update]**:-
>   Have done the complete System Anti-virus scan and no viruses,worms
>   were detected.The system is running clean

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. You should never start with: this is not my problem but... Always start with what you experience.

Comment: Have you run any diagnostics, SFC or System Restore? Have you run complete virus and malware scans?

Comment: @CharlieRB I have run the Epsa pre boot diagnostics and it showed a problem with the hard drive.Today I will run the complete anti virus scan

Comment: If you have a problem with the hard drive, it could be causing issues with all kinds of things. You may want to resolve that first.

Comment: In Control Panel / Network and Sharing Center / Change adapter settings, take a screenshot and post it here. Since this is a Dell laptop, go to the dell.com Support page to download and install the drivers for the two network adapters for your computer.

Comment: Please do an ipconfig and post the results. That will be very helpful.

Comment: @LPChip updated my post.Hope it clarifies the problem and added the screens to show where exactly my problem is

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you add one more thing? What is your question? What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling and re installing your networking drivers or rolling them back, connect to a AP then flush your dns, cmd; "ipconfig/flusdns" I believe then do a ipconfig/release and ipconfig/renew in cmd as well, reset the access point as well (AP).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing a few years ago, the quickest fix for me was to open up device manager from your Windows Control Panel, then under the "Network Adapters" section right click and uninstall the LAN/WIFI adapters (just make sure you DON'T tick the delete drivers during the uninstall process).  After the adapters have been removed click the "Action" menu and then "Scan for Hardware Changes", Windows should then automatically pick-up the adapters and reinstall them using the existing drivers.  This process tends to reset any customisations or corrupt configuration affecting how the adapters operate.